# Does interrupt exception to a sleeping thread release lock on the object

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

When the thread is on sleep state it still holds the lock for the object, and when it is interrupted, does it release the lock and go to ready state or will it continue the execution without changing the state?

Comment: sleep state doesn't exist, do you mean WAITING?

Comment: by sleep do you mean `Thread.sleep(x)` or `obj.wait()` ?

Comment: But if you call *Thread.sleep()* why you should continue to lock resources? Maybe you should release first and try to acquire the lock again on resume from sleep. Anyway, as the threadInterruption is an exception, it depends how the exception is handled. I would expect a finally block to clean up.

Answer (score 3):

> When it is interrupted, does it release the lock and go to ready state
>   or will it continue the execution without changing the state?

Being interrupted for a thread is only a status change (a flag that has been set) not a state change, and it has not effect on whether it will release the lock or not.

A thread holding an object's monitor will only release it if it calls `wait` (with or without timeout) on the corresponding object instance or when it will exit from the synchronized block, being interrupted or not doesn't change anything to this rule.

---

**Here is a simple code that shows the idea:**

```
// Used to make sure that thread t holds the lock before t2
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
Thread t = new Thread(
    () -> {
        synchronized (someObject) {
            // Release t2
            latch.countDown();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Sleeping " + i);
                    // Sleep 2 sec and keep holding the lock
                    Thread.sleep(2_000L);
                    System.out.println("Sleep over " + i);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Interrupted " + i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
Thread t2 = new Thread(
    () -> {
        try {
            // Wait to be release by t
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Trying to get in");
        synchronized (someObject) {
            System.out.println("In");
        }
    }
);
// Start the threads
t.start();
t2.start();
// Waiting 1 sec (< 2 sec) only before interrupting t
Thread.sleep(1_000L);
// Interrupt t
t.interrupt();
```

**Output:**

```
Trying to get in
Sleeping 1
Interrupted 1
Sleeping 2
Sleep over 2
In
```

As you can see in the output thread `t2` gets into the synchronized block (acquires the lock) only when thread `t` exits from the synchronized block. The fact that thread `t` has been interrupted did not make it release the lock.